# Xamarin Windows phone issues on Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am having issue developing apps with windows phones. I am currently on windows 7 and when I attempt to load cross platform samples I am greeted with a message that states cannot load windows phone platform. and  it shows unavailable for the windows files. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To work with Windows Phone 8 you need to have the relevant SDKs installed in Visual Studio. The Windows Phone 8 SDK only works on Windows 8 and higher, so you would need to upgrade from Windows 7 if you wish to use it.

The [Windows Phone 8 SDK download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35471) lists the system requirements.

If you are working with UWP, then the minimum requirement is Windows 10.